# SCTP redundant INIT_ACK

Tags: java, sctp

I'm developing a DRA replacement node written in JAVA uses RestComm and lksctp on Centos 7.

Based on SCTP's RFC the first message to establish an association is INIT, the other party should reply with INIT_ACK

What is happening, is that I'm receiving INIT_ACK many times even though I have not sent an INIT.


This behavior is mentioned in the RFC and it is advised that you ignore this redundant message.

I've checked lksctp's documentation https://linux.die.net/man/7/sctp and found some parameters you can tweak, I've changed prsctp_enable to false, by this I was able to remove the forward TSN parameter sent in INIT(in the original DRA this is parameter is not sent). But there's a parameter called ECN(Explicit Congestion Notification) which I was not able to remove from the INIT( this remains the only difference between the current DRA and my Replacement DRA).

So at the end, how avoid the redundant INIT_ACKs? any parameter tweaks which might help me

Answer (score 0):

Neither forward TSN nor ECN features related to the fact that you see multiple INI_ACK. There is no parameters to turn on multiple INIT_ACK response. 
I would suspect that it is either routing/traffic capturing issue, or you accidentally sent INITs. It would be worth capturing wireshark trace and have a look there what actually causing remote end to send INIT_ACK.